# In my ViewController, how can I pass a function as a parameter and keep [weak self]?

Tags: ios, swift

My initial method.  Everything works well.:

```
func fetchInitialItems(num: Int){
    firebaseRef?.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { [weak self] snapshot in
        if self != nil {
            //perform calculations
        }
    })
}
```

I want to move the closure to another method of its own:

```
func fetchBlock(snapshot: FDataSnapshot!){ 
    //perform calculations
}

func fetchInitialItems(num: Int){
    firebaseRef?.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: withBlock: self.fetchBlock)    
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? How do I make the second solution `[weak self]` ? I don't see a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
firebaseRef?.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { [weak self] snapshot in 
    self?.initialFetchBlock(snapshot)
})
```

I'm not sure we're allowed to use capture list outside of the closure.